# How to reduce voltage of a dynamo to 5 volts

Tags: voltage, charger

A friend and I are going to make a bike-powered charger. There is a video of KipKay making one. But he uses a 12 volt 6 watt dynamo and there is a schematic that he follows to lower it to 5 volts. Can we use a lower voltage dynamo instead? If so, how would we make the schematic of components?

Comment: You can use 6V 'dynamo' (which is in fact not a dynamo but a magneto), but it would require a buck-boost voltage regulator to cover all possible values of generated voltage. With 12V 'dynamo' buck regulator will be enough.

Comment: When you write "If so, how would we make the schematic of components?", are you asking for the name of an electronic CAD package, or something else? If it is simply to produce a picture, paper and pencil works for me. So I assume there is more to it than that.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with a higher voltage in this case is better because it allows you to regulate down to the desired voltage.  On a bike, the actual voltage will vary considerably.  A simple circuit would be use a buck regulator, which can only regulate down.  Since a buck is efficient, there is little harm in the input voltage being higher, within limits.  However, a "12 V" unit isn't going to put out such high voltages that it becomes a problem.

Measure the open circuit voltage of this unit with the bike going as fast as it ever will, then leave a little margin and design to that as the maximum input voltage.

Many bike generators actually produce AC, so you need a circuit that rectfies the output and bucks it down to 5 V or whatever you want to use.  It would probably be a good idea to include some logic to positively shut down the 5 V when there isn't enough input voltage to support it rather than letting it sag.  If you know whatever is connected to this "5 V" line isn't going to mind being at lower voltages for extended periods of time, then you can skip this part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if it is a power bank? Or an iPhone?

Answer (score -1):

the voltage of a dynamo is quite bad with lots of spiks. so i will use some TVS diode to protect your input of the buck converter.
and to save power beter use some shotky diodes to change the AC voltage to a DC